# How to use MATCH AGAINST in Wordpress WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, sql-order-by

I have implemented a search page which search through post_title and custom fields, however i want to assign more weight-age to post_title column , so it look in to post_title field first and then other content.

I know it can be done by giving more weightage to post_title column and finding relevence by MATCH CASE , but i have no idea how to do it in wordpress.

I don't want to use custom query.